# Backgroundworker - Data Binding - View Update

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, viewmodel, backgroundworker

I have a requirement to select bulk data (million rows) and then update the DB Table. Now, I am reading the data chunk by chunk in a `BackgroundWorker` (as the usage being specified in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

I have a `ViewModel` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all the public properties are bound to GUI via the `BindingSource` component - the classic WinForms way:

Problem is that all my logic is in one `ViewModel` class. How do I segregate my logic in a much better way ? The data fetching and update logic is in a loop in the `DoWork()` method and it signals the UI via the `ReportProgress` method of `BackgroundWorker`.

EDIT - I do not have to display any kind of data on the GUI other than the progress. Its just a one time tool. Suggestions?

> EDIT - Solution -
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MVPVMWindowsForms.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution -
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MVPVMWindowsForms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Move all of your BackgroundWorker logic into a Model class, and make it execute work asynchronously.  Supply events for notifying your ViewModel when new records are available.

In general, your ViewModels shouldn't have much knowledge of threading (other than maybe a Dispatcher.Invoke here and there).  A ViewModel should merely accept input from the View, call the Model and then update the View with INotifyPropertyChanged.  Not much logic should exist in the ViewModel.

*You will probably also want to use ObservableCollection, but it sounds like you haven't gotten that far yet.*

Comment: Updated my question with solution